# Why is setup.py executed twice by pip?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

Consider a very simple `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

print('WAAAAAAAAA') # executed twice!

setup(
    name="foo",
    version="190425",
    description="bar",
    author="Developers",
    author_email="me@domain.com",
    install_requires=["pyzmq", "pybullet"],
    packages=find_packages(),
)
```

Why exactly is the module loaded twice when running `pip install . -v` and what can I do to guard the code so it runs only once per invocation of `pip`, just like `setup()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer turns out to be that `pip install .` executes `setup.py` twice (the verbose output actually says it) since it executes the `egg_info` subcommand and then the `install` subcommand.

A possible solution is to check if `sys.argv[1] == 'install'` and only then execute whatever is desired.

Comment: You might want to do a more comprehensive check, e.g. `sys.argv[1] in ('install', 'sdist', 'bdist_wheel')`, or consider a list of commands where guarded code should *not* run, which might be safer. The thing to note is that adapting behaviour depending on command risks the creation of inconsistent information, so you'll want to be really cautious with this.
BTW, nowadays pip runs `dist_info` rather than `egg_info`

Comment: What we'd need from PyPA to do this properly would be an API providing the setup script's run count relative to the meta-call (e.g. pip install), specifically info if it's the first run. (Note that this cannot be determined from the command since pip runs dist_info/bdist_wheel, but build omits the dist_info call). Ideally, setup.py should be executed only once in the first place - in theory, it should be possible to collect all data in one go.